# How to know the topic(s) i am currently subscribed to?

Tags: mqtt, paho, android-open-accessory

I am using `Paho MQTT` library, but I do not know how to know if i am currently subscribed to a certain topic so that, no to subscribe to it again.

is there any way to know if a specific topic i am subscribed to it or not??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have to explicitly keep track of what you subscribed to yourself.